# Maven release plugin with git + developer connection

Tags: git, maven, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to use maven release plugin for creating a branch from trunk.

Ex. repository.git/
                 child1/
                 child2/

The plugin creates a new branch that contains my entire repository.
How can i restrict it to create a branch that contains only child1 ?

Currently the pom.xml connection, developer connection and url are as follows :

```
<scm>
  <connection>scm:git:ssh://githost/repository.git</connection>
  <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://githost/repository.git</developerConnection>
  <url>scm:git:ssh://githost/repository.git</url>
  <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
```

In svn we used to achieve this by using the absolute path to child1 in developerConnection.

Thanks,

Gayathri

Comment: Branches in git are [different](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12160744/877115) from branches in SVN. What exactly are you trying to do? Divide the repository in two, or something else?

Comment: Say, i want to release only child1. so i don't want child2 to be present in child1's release branch. In other words, i don't want to increment the version of child2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727450/releasing-a-multi-module-maven-project-with-git helped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Releasing a multi-module maven project with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727450/releasing-a-multi-module-maven-project-with-git)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Releasing a multi-module maven project with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727450/releasing-a-multi-module-maven-project-with-git) helps + You need to upgrade to 2.3.2 version of maven-release-plugin