# maven-release-plugin in multi-module project having a seperate git repository for each module

Tags: git, maven, maven-release-plugin

I wonder if it's possible to use the maven-release-plugin in a multi module project where each module has its own git repository? Something like this:

```
parent/
  .git/
  pom.xml
module1/
  .git/
  pom.xml
```

I set up a simple test (under linux) and it fails for the "git add" command (simplyfied):

```
cd parent && git add -- pom.xml /.../module1/pom.xml
```

The error message is

```
fatal: /.../module1/pom.xml: '/.../module1/pom.xml' is outside repository
```

I understand that this git command can't work. Is maven-release-plugin able to do a seperate "git add" command for each repository?

Just for the case the answer is NO: Assume i only have a single git repository. Does it matter whether i use a flat hierarchy or a nested one?

Are there any other options for automated versioning/releasing and keeping multiple git repositories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since maven-release-plugin 2.0-beta-5 they added a new property called [commitByProject](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#commitByProject) that in my case (that happens to be exactly your case) let us commit per project each submodule (referenced from root pom with 'git submodule add' strategy). And this gets the job done!!

mvn release:prepare -DcommitByProject=true

Answer (score 0):

You can use git submodules to have other git repositories inside your git repository. But if your `module1` have a dependency to `parent` through maven (i.e `<parent>` or parent has dependencyManagement), there seems like module1 isn't really a standalone module and should not have it's own repository in my opinion.

About hierarchy I prefer nested ones to more easily see parent and modules.

Comment: submodules seem to be no option: i get "fatal: Pathspec 'module1/pom.xml' is in submodule 'module1'"

Comment: What exactly were you trying to do?

Comment: I set up an example: Just like in my intial question, but now module1 is nested within parent as a git submodule. A "mvn release:prepare" in parent will then lead to the cited error message.

If your question is more in the direction of why i just don't use a single repository: The code is currently under svn, each module has its own trunk, branches,... Our developers are used to only see the history of the project they are working on, and i am a little bit afraid that they get confused if commits of different modules are mixed / interfere.