# Maven Release prepare fails with Git submodules

Tags: git, maven, git-submodules, maven-release-plugin

We have a multi-module Maven project, where the modules are also Git submodules.

When I perform mvn release:prepare on the parent project, I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project big-project-parent: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-add command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] fatal: Pathspec 'basic-utils\pom.xml' is in submodule 'basic-utils'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check first, as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55165872/6309), is the [`commitByProject`](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#commitByProject) can help (maven release 2.0+)

```
mvn release:prepare -DcommitByProject=true
```

[MRELEASE-726](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-726) states that Git support has been improved with 2.5.x., so make sure to use a recent maven release plugin, 3.0+.

Comment: I had the same problem. Setting the parameter commitByProject gets rid of the first error, but gives me a new one: "Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally". But fetching from the remote shows me the opposite. I have local changes, caused by Maven having made a commit in one of the submodules. Still searching for a solution.

Comment: @Clon Interesting. You might need to write a separate question for this (adding more details about OS, Git and maven version)